# Where to use a "noun + noun"?

Tags: nouns

Sometimes I cannot understand how to use it. For, example

> a model car

This expression makes sense and means "the best car".

Another example. I have an exercise and a guide for the exercise. A native speaker told me that "an exercise guide" makes no sense and that I should use "a guide of an exercise" instead.

Could anybody give a clear explanation about two nouns in a row?

Comment: "a model car" without context is more likely to be a scale model (a toy: google images for "model car"). Regarding the exercise guide, your native speaker has lied to you.

Comment: @horatio, has lied?

Comment: the person is a liar: "an exercise guide" makes perfect sense. Either the person who told you that lied about being a native speaker, or they are playing a game with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Model car**

> "*a model car without context is more likely to be a scale model (a toy: google images for model car). Regarding the exercise guide, your native speaker has lied to you.*" – horatio

### **Playing a game.**

> "the person is a liar: "an exercise guide" makes perfect sense. Either the person who told you that lied about being a native speaker, or they are playing a game with you." – horatio

### **Two nouns in a row**

> "*In grammar, genitive (abbreviated gen; also called the possessive case or second case) is the grammatical case that marks a noun as modifying another noun. It often marks a noun as being the possessor of another noun; however, it can also indicate various other relationships than possession: certain verbs may take arguments in the genitive case, and it may have adverbial uses (see Adverbial genitive).*" -Wikipedia

### **First noun is modifying noun**

> "*Placing the modifying noun in the genitive case is one way to indicate that two nouns are related in a genitive construction. Modern English typically does not morphologically mark nouns for a genitive case in order to indicate a genitive construction; instead, it uses either the 's clitic or a preposition (usually of). However, the personal pronouns do have distinct possessive forms. There are various other ways to indicate a genitive construction, as well. For example, many Afroasiatic languages place the head noun (rather than the modifying noun) in the construct state.*" -Wikipedia

### **WIKIPEDIA**

> ["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive" -The Internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive)